# Lock-sync several standalone scripts modifying one spreadsheet in Google Apps Script

Tags: multithreading, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet modified by code from two or more standalone Apps Script files. I need a lock that would enable me to sync code from all those Apps Script files.

Thinking in terms of Java-like locking using an arbitrary object, locking using the object of the Spreadsheet being modified would be sufficient.

Class LockService seems to lack that option, as there are just these three:

`getDocumentLock() Gets a lock that prevents any user of the current document from concurrently running a section of code.` This one looks pretty close but it gets a lock of the "current" document which doesn't make sense with standalone scripts and doesn't allow an arbitrary document to be specified.

`getScriptLock() Gets a lock that prevents any user from concurrently running a section of code.` Mutiple script files are running their own code so this doesn't help either.

`getUserLock() Gets a lock that prevents the current user from concurrently running a section of code.` In the worst case this might be used but it solves only the special case when all the scripts are run by the same user. Another thing is that it leads to a need of special shared storage of finer "sublocks" in case one doesn't want to settle with using really just one global lock for the entire time of all the critical sections - that gets complicated and slow.

What I have tried is to implement my own following locking mechanism using a dedicated cell of the spreadsheet containing a semaphore value using the following logic but it's error prone to implement and use, not totally reliable in locking and I assume also slow considering the extra reading and writing of spreadsheet cells:

```
Script S1 (and similarly for scripts S2, S3, ...):
Read value of the cell A1
If A1 is empty write "S1" into A1, else start over
Flush the write
Wait for 5 seconds
Read value of A1
If the value is "S1" execute critical section, else start over
After executing the critical section erase contents of A1
Flush the erase
```

What would be the best way to lock-sync over one document modified by multiple standalone App Scripts?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to accomplish that with google apps script.  It might be possible if you try placing all of the functionality into one script and use lockService on that.  Also I'm not familiar with your scripting  language.

Comment: @Cooper Thanks, I still hope there's a better way. The scripting language of the snippet is a pseudocode. Apps scripts are being written in JavaScript.

Comment: "What would be the best way to lock-sync over one document modified by multiple standalone App Scripts?" You are asking about a hypothetical situation; you haven't described your scenario, nor your data/layout, nor the multiple scripts. Please Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without this information, I think your question is seeking an opinion and is probably off-topic.

Comment: I'd need to know a lot more about what you are doing.  I was throwing out an idea.  I have no idea whether it would work for you or not.  There is hardly ever just one way of doing something and different methods have the advantages and disadvantages and you have to consider them based upon many factors.  I can't answer such a genral question.  And really I think it's out of the scope of this forum